# XML validation against XSD files

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I want to validate my xml file against XSD file which has attributeGroup as below.

I am not able to validate the same using:

```
XmlTextReader file = new XmlTextReader("xsdFilePath");
schemas.Add("", file);

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("xmlFilePath");
xmlDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
{
    valdiationMessages.Add(e.Message);
}, true);
return valdiationMessages;
```

Regards,
Kishor M